# How to execute jarsigner with specific JRE

Tags: java

We're using a 3rd-party Java security provider which is correctly installed for the JRE 8 on the system I work on. Now I want to use the jarsigner tool from the JDK 11 on my system to work with this 3rd-party Java security provider. How to tell jarsigner that it should execute using my installed JRE and not using the java.exe in the JDK folder?

Comment: Why do you think that `jarsigner.exe` uses `java.exe`? If you need to run `jarsigner` version 8 you have to install JDK 8. If you just want to use the security provider's resources run `jarsigner -providerClass [provider-class-name]`

Comment: I want to run jarsigner with the configuration from my JRE 8 (note: there is no JRE 11).

Comment: `jarsigner` is a separate executable which is part of JDK but not part of JRE. As far as I know, there is no way (and also no _need_) to link `jarsigner.exe` with a specific JRE. You can run it idependently. What exactly do you mean by _configuration from my JRE 8_? What is the exact problem that you are facing?

Comment: I've created a new issue for the exact problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188671/use-custom-security-provider-with-jdk11s-jarsigner

Note: keytool from the JRE works, as the JRE is configured correctly (java.security file + files in lib/ext folder). keytool/jarsigner from JDK do not work correctly - because the configuration is missing from whatever kind of JRE they are using.

Comment: BTW: I'm pretty sure that jarsigner.exe is a simple wrapper executable which calls into a java application.